# Trying to save yml object in Cygwin

Tags: yaml, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin64 on Win 10, and when I open vi in Cygwin64, it works. But when I try to create yml object, I can't save it in Cygwin 64

```
vi webserver.yml
```

With this command I can add the YMAL configuration file, but after that
I can't save it I tried all of these commands. This is a screenshot of the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suDRh.png)

:q
:x
:wq
:q!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkfeE.png)

I'm stuck because these commands. And when I try to close, it doesn't save it either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to save the file locally and than copy it to the server ? It does not seem a Cygwin problem

Comment: I'm not sure how to copy it directly to the server

Comment: It looks like you didn't quit Insert-Mode before entering the commands. Be sure to hit escape before entering the commands.

Comment: I did but still the same resutl